# How to use finite differences to find approximate functions for a set of data?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the data:

x: 0  2  4   6  8  10  12  14  16

y: 5 -8 -11 -9  4  23  52  89  131

How would you use finite differences to find the approximate function to model this data? There is no common difference as it appears but plotting the data gives a quadratic/cubic shape. How can this be done?

Comment: Note that the $x$ values are in arithmetic progression. If you want a polynomial function $f$ of degree $8$ to run through the given $(x,y)$ points, then define $f(2x)=g(x)$ and then construct a difference table for degree $8$ polynomial $g$ and reconstruct $g$. Once you get $g$, you can easily get $f$.

Comment: [Here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/method-of-differences/) is the link to the wiki on Method of Finite Differences. You can read how to construct a difference table and reconstruct the polynomial there.